# unbold title and no line break for a subsection

Tags: line-breaking

How can we unbold the title of a subsection and suppress the line break, like it was done in the following image? The answers in the duplicate deal with how to do that for all the subsection. I want to do that, just only for one subsection. For the others, I like that style with the breakline

Best,
Layth[image]

Comment: Your request for having one subsection with a _completely different style_ than **the other subsections** is strange, but I agree that it's not a duplicate anymore. However, please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\normalfont\large\itshape}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

Comment: I want todo  that, just only for one subsection. For the others, I like that steel with the brekline.

Comment: You did not specify that earlier!